# unable to get get data of my container from the browser using Azure SAS URL

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a SAS URL for my container to access it from the browser but i am getting below issue

```
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:dfcac5c5-401e-003a-0d29-d7fa86000000 Time:2023-08-25T07:55:08.7233034Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

I have created an SAS URL for my container to access it from the browser but I am getting the below issue

Comment: make sure you are using correct sas token with all privileges needed.

Comment: Hi, @Nani Chaatla can you please provide the code for how you are creating the sas Url?

Answer (score 0):

> `AuthenticationFailed` Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.RequestId:dfcac5c5-401e-003a-0d29-d7fa86000000 Time:2023-08-25T07:55:08.7233034Z< /Message>< AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.< /AuthenticationErrorDetail> < /Error >

The above error occurs when the signature in the `Authorization` header of your SAS URL is not well-formed.

You can use the below Python to create SAS_token with container URL to get the list of blobs using Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import generate_account_sas, ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import requests

sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name="venkat123",
    account_key="xxxxxx",
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(object=True,container=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True,list=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

container_name = "test"
account_url = "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net"

url = f"{account_url}/{container_name}?restype=container&comp=list&{sas_token}"
print(url)
```

**Output:**

```
https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test?restype=container&comp=list&se=2023-08-25T13%3A25%3A42Z&sp=rl&sv=2023-01-03&ss=b&srt=co&sig=xxxxxxxxxx
```

When I copied the URL and pasted it in the browser it worked perfectly.

**Browser:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[List Blobs (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad)